# R/Sweave/Latex - Place comment in table (xtable)

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I created a table using R and sweave in LaTeX. A sweave example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<label=tab1, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
mData <- data.frame(employee, salary) 
print(xtable(mData, caption = "Salary", align="ccc"), caption.placement="top", hline.after = c(c(-1, 0), nrow(mData)), include.rownames=FALSE) 
@

\end{document}
```

The basic LaTeX structure of the table is

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

To save me a lot of work I use the print and xtable functions in R to create the table code in LaTeX. But now I want to add some text between the \end{tabular} and \end{table} statements. The add.to.row argument in the print function does not help, as statements are only placed before \end{tabular}. How can I solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would just edit the xtable object -- save it to a variable and insert the desired text between tabular and table environments.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to use xtable, remove the table environment *floating = FALSE* and package threeparttable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<label=tab1, echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
mData <- data.frame(employee, salary) 
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
xt<-xtable(mData, caption = "Salary", align="ccc") 
print(xt,floating = FALSE,
    caption.placement="top",
    hline.after = c(c(-1, 0), nrow(mData)),
    include.rownames=FALSE,
    file="test.tex"
    )
@


\begin{table}[h]
\caption{A table with notes in the end}
  \begin{center}
     \begin{threeparttable}
       % INPUT YOUR TEX HERE :
       \input{test.tex}
     \begin{tablenotes}
       \item[1] aaaa; \item[2] bbbb
     \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
   \end{center}
 \label{table:tablewithnotes}
 \end{table}     
\end{document}`enter code here
```

[image: Table output]